# Removing an imageview background color

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide, android-image

I'm using `Glide library` for downloading images and displaying them in my adapter, the problem is, after it sets the images, they get a background that is not in the downloaded image, the `ImageView` added this color to them

this is an example:

[image]

as you can see it has a very light green background color, the image it self has white background.

things I've tried so far:

- set white background color in my `xml layout`
- set `transparent background color`
- used `View.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)` in my adapter
- used `View.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000)` in adapter

nothing worked...
how can I get rid of it?

::EDit

the layout file attached :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:backgroundTint="#fff"
            android:background="#fff" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you add your image url?

Comment: can you attach the original image?

Comment: can you post your layout file? the background may be not in the imageView.

Comment: try use fitcenter in glide requestoption

Comment: you can try                     android:backgroundTint=""

Comment: thanks all for reply , this is the orginal image : http://marketaghili.ir/Opitures/sm35617735066680.jpg

Comment: this is a different image that youve posted

Comment: can you please post your layout file, also code

Comment: @InfusionAnalysts i've tried , still the same

Comment: @P.Juni they all the same , they have no background color

Comment: how about setting `@null` in xml, like `android:background="@null"` ?

Comment: @ManojPerumarath I edit my post and attached the layout file

Comment: @NavidAbutorab please replace your image with transparent background. You image has white background

Comment: @P.Juni just did not worked

Comment: @NcitCosmos i've tied , I set null and transparent background for it but it doesn't work

Comment: @NavidAbutorab I don't mean to say about your layout. The image has white background. Please save the image from that link you will see white background. This leads the problem. If you add transparent image then your problem will solved

Comment: @NavidAbutorab I download the image from the link that you mention above has white background.

Comment: @NcitCosmos yes, it has a white background , but when I show it in my imageview it gets that light green background

Answer (score -1):

[image: Image with transparent background][image: Image that you have on link]

Look at the image, which has a white background. Try to add a transparent image and your problem will be solved. I removed the background of that image. Look at the difference between these two images.

Comment: thanks for reply , If you mean I use a png image , it can't because I've no written the webservice , I just know every image converts to a jpg file....